# Logic in IF statement

Tags: asp-classic

Can anybody tell me what the following logic would do?

```
if ((intOne and intTwo) = intThree)
```

I've got a feeling it checks that either intOne or intTwo matches intThree, but I'd like to know for certain. Unfortunately Google doesn't seem to have much support at all when it comes to asp classic.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In most languages, that would compare the result of the `and` operation to `intThree`. If a logical and returns 1 on true and 0 on false, like in C, then it compares 1 or 0 to `intThree'. If it returns the first true value or a special False value, like in Python, then it would compare `intOne` iff `intOne` is nonzero, otherwise `intTwo` to `intThree`.

Comment: I'm a bit hazy on this, but I remember it being a massive WTF. I'm fairly sure none of the answers so far have guessed correctly.

Comment: True is actually -1 in vbscript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zy95hw%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is pretty specific:

> The **And** operator also performs a bitwise comparison of identically positioned bits in two numeric expressions and sets the corresponding bit in result according to the following table:
>   ... *(truth table for AND follows)*

So the expression bitwise-ANDs the first two ints, and then compares the result to the third int.

Here's the same evaluation in C, for comparison.

```
if( (intOne & intTwo) == intThree ) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

My VBScript is a bit rusty, but I would guess that the `(intOne and intTwo)` section evaluates to `true`. My thinking is that it's only checking if the vars exist.

If you want to achieve an either or, it would probably look more like:

```
If intOne = intThree OR intTwo = intThree Then
  ...
End If
```

If both need to be equal to `intThree` then you would do

```
If intOne = intThree AND intTwo = intThree Then
  ...
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know .. the 'and' operator in vbscript is a boolean operator .. which means intOne and intTwo should be expressions or values that result in boolean.

Wrong syntax i think ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the syntax is correct, but the logic is saying if BOTH intOne and IntTwo equal intThree then ...

```
if intOne = intThree and intTwo = intThree
```